# WhatsApp error when trying to reinstall

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I have installed and restored WhatsApp a million times or so when flashing and switching between ROMs.

Last night I tried something funny, and it cost me too much. I tried to install WhatsApp for another number (my phone has dual SIM). While SMS verification was happening, it got registered via my previously registered WhatsApp number.

Now even after I deleted the new no. account, I am still not able to get my old account back. When I give my old number, it doesn’t ask for SMS verification, and goes to local backup directly, but fails there and throws error.

On the other hand, I can verify the account, but cannot restore all my messages.

My messages are quite important.

Comment: The title is all about the error, but what's the error? Please post a screenshot or exactly quote it.

Answer (score 0):

There is one way I hope will fix your problem:

1. Go to your phone settings
2. Open Application manager
3. Scroll and find WhatsApp and then click it
4. You will see a screen with application detail
5. Click on **Clear cache** and then click on **Clear data** buttons

It will make your WhatsApp as a fresh application. Then try to log in with your old account .

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply .....I have tried all that, i even uninstalled and installed latest version..the thing is that...after verification of sms, it does not complete the restoration...it unfortunately stops...and quits

Comment: it might be related to back-end synch problem .. do one thing completely uninstall the application and then install the fresh what’s App from google play.

Comment: @firelord :- ok I will keep in mind in future

Comment: hi, yes.. i installed fresh app..alone..i even reset my phone....and then after number verification, it asked for restoring backup, after it started around 80% of restoration..it stopped unfortunately.and from then on.its the same issue..doesnt restore any message

Comment: @sriniketan :- I think this issue is related with device memory .Please check whether your device have available space .Hope this will help you rest you need to post your problem on whatsapp

Comment: i have plenty of memory, i even tried this after factory reset and wipe, and also used aftermarket apps like whatsapp+ aswell, still no use. Its the same, i guess the problem is on server.